# play framework 2.0 localhost is not working

Tags: java, playframework

After installtion play framewrok in my pc i was create system path in environment variables.

and open the browser type http://localhost:9000 it doesnot open anything whats the

wrong where can i declare this default ip.

Comment: Did you create and start an app?

Comment: Did you follow the tutorial to its end?

Comment: i created yabe app in playframework2.0 still its not working

Answer (score 0):

I remove installed sbt, remove ~/.ivy2 and ~/.m2 dirs, after sample play apps is work.
(on my home pc, i remove only ~/.m2)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you need to open command line (with Start >> type "cmd").

Navigate to the place where your got Play-Framework installed and type "play". After that press "run".

Now you should be able to get localhost:9000 working.